# split int value into separate digits

Tags: java

I want to split my int value into digits. eg if the no. is 542, the result should be 5,4,2.

I have 2 options.
1) Convert int into String & then by using getCharArray(), i can have separate characters & then i will convert them back into int values.

2) Convert int into String, without converting it into char array, iterate it & get all digits.

Is there any other way to solve the problem. If not, which of the option will be fast?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
List<Integer> digits(int i) {
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(i > 0) {
        digits.add(i % 10);
        i /= 10;
    }
    return digits;
}
```

Comment: @Steve fair enough - also fails for negative numbers. Special cases left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @Eric That depends on your definition of backwards, now doesn't it? It's the whole "big endian, small endian" debate all over again.

Comment: @All: through this logic i just meant to calculate sum of all digits of numbers, so whether the number is positive or not doesn't bother me. My main intention is to calculate to product of 2 nos. by using addition only.

Comment: I just realized it would be better for me to use `LinkedList<Integer>` instead of `ArrayList`, since there is no need for random access here.

Comment: After thinking about this some more, I think `ArrayList` is the right choice after all because of the sequential memory and the high likelihood that it will be accessed in an iterator. Also its default value is 10 which is perfect for an int.

Answer (score 10):

Use the mod 10 rule...

```
 List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 while (n > 0) {
     digits.add(n%10);
     n/=10;
 }
```

Comment: The spirit of the question seems to be avoiding the conversion to a string and back again which is what I focused on solving.

Answer (score 7):

```
int num = 542;

if (num<0) num=-num; // maybe you'd like to support negatives
List<Integer> digits = new LinkedList<Integer>();

while (num>0) {
    digits.add(0, num%10);
    num=num/10;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits.toArray())); // [5, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

divide by ten and get remainders, put them in a collection/array of your choice, keep doing this until there the quotient is zero and all you have is a remainder

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Stack instead of an ArrayList if the ordering was a big issue. When popped the digits off the stack you would get them in the correct order, with the most significant digit first.

Answer (score 1):

```
int digits(int i) {
    int num=0;
    while(i > 0) {
        num *= 10;
        num += i % 10;
        i /= 10;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will split the digits for you. Now put them into an array instead of printing them out and do whatever you want with the digits. If you want to add them, you could replace the `System.out` with something like `sum += z;`.

```
public class Splitter {
    public static int numLength(int n) {
        int length;        
        for (length = 1; n % Math.pow(10, length) != n; length++) {}        
        return length;
    }
    public static void splitNums(double x){
        double y, z, t = x;   

        for (int p = numLength((int)x)-1; p >= 1; p--){
             y = t % Math.pow(10, (numLength((int)(t))-1));
             z = ((t - y)/Math.pow(10, p));             
             t = t - (z * Math.pow(10, p)); 

             System.out.println(Math.abs((int)(z)));
        }   
        System.out.println(Math.abs((int)(t)));          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm will split primitive "int" into single digits. It starts from the last digit up to the first one.

class IntegerSplitterDemo {

```
static boolean digitChoper(int num) {

    for(int i = 10; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i *= 10  ) {

        //Starts from the last digit so it will display the int in reverse order
        int remainder = (i == 10) ? num % 10 : (num % i / (i /10));

        //You can store the remainder value into ArrayList
        System.out.print(remainder + " ");

        //stop iterating the loop
        if(num % i == num) { break; }       
    }
    System.out.println("");
    return true;
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] num = {0, 371, 372, 678, 432, 569, 341, 371, 567, 2569874};
    for(int number : num) {
        digitChoper(number);
    }
} // end main
```

}