# how to add two integers in a number

Tags: java, numbers

I am writing a credit card validation program. I am trying to see if a product is more that 1 digit long (i.e: 10), if it is I need to add the two integers together. For example 10 would be `1 + 0`, which equals 1, how do I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
public class CreditCard{
public static void main(String args[]){

    //Take in a 16 digit credit card number
    Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);
    int num[]=new int[16];
    int i=0;


    for (i=0;i<num.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a 16 digit credit card number");
        num[i]=in.nextInt();

    }
    if (num.length < 16 || num.length > 16)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
     else
    {

        //multiply every other number by 2, starting with place 16, and find the sum(sum1)
         int num1 = (num[16] * 2);
         int num2 = (num[14] * 2);
         int num3 = (num[12] * 2);
         int num4 = (num[10] * 2);
         int num5 = (num[8] * 2);
         int num6 = (num[6] * 2);
         int num7 = (num[4] * 2);
         int num8 = (num[2] * 2);

         if( num1 > 9)

         int sum1 = (num[16] * 2) + (num[14] * 2) + (num[12] * 2) + (num[10] * 2) + (num[8] * 2) + (num[6] * 2) + (num[4] *2) + (num[2] *2);
         int sum2 = (num[15] + num[13] + num[11] + num[9] + num[7] + num[5] + num[3] + num[1]);

        int totalSum = sum1 + sum2;
        if (totalSum % 10 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid card number!!");
        }
        else

        {  
            System.out.println(" Valid Credit Card Number!!");


        }

      }      
}
}
```

Comment: So you're asking how to convert `"123"` to `1 + 2 + 3 = 6`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple way would be

```
if (num1 > 9) num1 = num1-9
```

This works if you look at how the original numbers look after multiplying by 2.

```
num  num*2  result
0    0      0
1    2      2
2    4      4
3    6      6
4    8      8
5    10     1
6    12     3
7    14     5
8    16     7
9    18     9
```

Comment: ok,but then I would have to change num1's type to boolean.How do i implement boolean into the beginning of my program

Comment: @mdt - sorry, I misplaced the closing parenthesis. I've edited to correct that.

Comment: My code still has errors, I believe it's because of my input.  How do I have the user input 16 digits and then use those digits for the calculations

Answer (score 2):

Rather than re-inventing the wheel you could have a look at the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) which is a widely used checksum algorithim used to validate credit card numbers. Here is a [Java version](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers#Java).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to implement the [Luhn checkdigit algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) .

Try the apache commons [`LuhnCheckDigit()`](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/checkdigit/LuhnCheckDigit.html) utility method of the [Apache commons-validator library](http://commons.apache.org/validator/).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into splitting an integer into digits first: [split int value into separate digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196186/split-int-value-into-seperate-digits)

Answer (score 0):

If Blender's comment is correct, you could do it like this:

```
int num=123; // or whatever
String str=Integer.toString(num);
int total=0;
if(str.length()>1){
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        total+=Integer.parseInt(str.charAt(i));
    }
}
System.out.println(total);
```

(I haven't run this, so there are probably some errors in there)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code to calculate the total should be

```
int totalSum = 0;
for (i=0; i<num.length; i+=2) {
    totalSum+=num[i+1];
    if (num[i+2]>4) {
        totalSum+=1+((num[i+2]*2) % 10); 
    } else {
        totalSum+=num[i+2]*2;
    }
}
```

This avoids any slow string conversions.