# Split 4 digit value into 3 integers

Tags: java

I'm trying to split a user entered 4 digit value (ex. 0123) into 3 integer values (ex. 0,1,23) and then do some calculations using the individual values. The way that I have it set up here is just for testing purposes to make sure that my math works. They user would enter 0123 and they should be broken up into int variables. (0, 1, and 23) and saved. Then they are put back together in the end after calculations are completed and given back to the user. I can't seem to quite figure out how to split the input into this pattern. Thanks!

}

Comment: Are the input and output a String, or integers as you have them here?

Comment: How do you know what the boundaries are; is it always 1-digit, 1-digit, 2-digits? I'm a little confused though, you don't even have a four-digit number in the code.

Comment: Please explain the logic that should yield `0`, `1` and `23` from `0123`. First digit, second digit, third and fourth digits?

Comment: You can't seem to figure out what? Also, there's no real reason to encapsulate those variables (make them private). I don't even think that will compile because they're non-static variables accessed in a static context (assuming the `class` that `main` is in is non-static).

Comment: Take a look at substrings. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int) Use that to split your input up based on required lengths. You can parse the integer out of the results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196186/split-int-value-into-seperate-digits?rq=1

Comment: Yes, first digit, second digit, third and fourth digits. I removed the static variables at the top. I moved them and forgot to delete them. I just can't figure out how to split the input value into the desired chunks and then save them in order to manipulate them with the calculations.

Comment: Input and output could be either strings or integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would split it up given the rules from the comments above,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] tests = new String[] { "0123", "9876" };
  for (String test : tests) {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(test.substring(0, 1));
    int b = Integer.parseInt(test.substring(1, 2));
    int c = Integer.parseInt(test.substring(2));
    System.out.printf("%s = a=%d, b=%d, c=%d\n", test, a,
        b, c);
  }
}
```

Output is (as described) -

```
0123 = a=0, b=1, c=23
9876 = a=9, b=8, c=76
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.substring()`

An example method:

```
//I change your int into a string for easier parsing.

    public int subber(int num) {
        String myNum = Integer.toString(num);
        int digit1 = myNum.substring(0,1);
        int digit2 = myNum.substring(1,2);
        int digit3 = myNum.substring(2,4);

        //Do whatever



    }
```