# Seperate integers from 1 variable into different variables

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Not sure how to explain this the best but I have a variable with 4 int's in it. Is there a simple way to extract the 4 int's into 4 seperate var's?

Example:
The variable contains: `4567`

And then the output is:

```
   var1 = 4 
   var2 = 5
   var3 = 6
   var4 = 7
```

Comment: Is this 4567 an int or a String, or something else?

Comment: Yes the 4567 is a int variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split int value into separate digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196186/split-int-value-into-separate-digits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
val input = 4567

val var1 = input / 1000
val var2 = (input % 1000) / 100
val var3 = (input % 100) / 10
val var4 = (input % 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way can be:

```kotlin
val n = 4567
val (var1, var2, var3, var4) = "$n".map { it.digitToInt() }
```

Note that this will fail if number contains less than 4 digits.